# nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've seen other questions similar to this one, but none that are exactly the same (I'm still somewhat of a beginner). If there is another thread that is the same just let me know! Thanks!!

**UPDATE:**
I forgot to add this code. Which is a migration file to add the quantity.

```
class AddQuantityToProductItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :product_items, :quantity, :integer, default: 1
  end
end
```

I keep getting the error "nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal" from the code below (**ProductItem Model:**)

```
class ProductItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart

  def total_price
    product.price * quantity
  end  
end
```

Here is the **Cart Model:**

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = product_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = product_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    end
    current_item
  end

  def total_price
    product_items.to_a.sum{|item| item.total_price}
  end
end
```

**Product Model:**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  before_destroy :ensure_not_product_item
  has_many :product_items
  validates :title, :description, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb:       "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  def ensure_not_product_item
    if product_items.empty?
      return true
    else
      errors.add(:base, 'Product Items')
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

**ProductItems Controller:**

```
class ProductItemsController < ApplicationController

  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
  before_action :set_product_item, only: [:show, :destroy]

  def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @product_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
    if @product_item.save
      redirect_to shop_url, notice: 'Your Product was added to the cart!'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_product_item
    @product_item = ProductItem.find(params[:id])
  end

  def product_item_params
    params.require(:product_item).permit(:product_id)
  end

end
```

Code for Product Items and Products from **schema.rb**

```
create_table "product_items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "product_id"
  t.integer  "cart_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer  "quantity"
  t.index ["cart_id"], name: "index_product_items_on_cart_id"
  t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_product_items_on_product_id"
end

create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "image"
  t.text     "description"
  t.decimal  "price"
  t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
  t.string   "image_file_name"
  t.string   "image_content_type"
  t.integer  "image_file_size"
  t.datetime "image_updated_at"
end
```

If any other files are needed, I'll gladly post them. I'm sure it's something really simple, I just can't seem to figure it out. Maybe I'm trying too hard to find the problem. Lol.
Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: the one thing you're missing is the text of the error. it will include a file name and line number to show where its coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of it, you are not initialising the `quantity` attribute when you create a new product item.

You could either initialise the `quantity` attribute in the by adding an `after_initialize` block in `ProductItem`

```
class ProductItem < ApplicationRecord
  after_initialize do
    self.quantity ||= 1
  end
end
```

Or, you could set the `quantity` attribute in the `Cart#add_product` method when you create a product item:

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = product_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      # initialize the quantity value when creating a new item
      current_item = product_items.build(product_id: product_id, quantity: 1)
    end
    current_item
  end
end
```

Yet another method would be to set a default value in the `ProductItem#total_price` method:

```
class ProductItem < ApplicationRecord
  def total_price
    product.price * (quantity || 1)
  end  
end
```

Personally, I would go with `after_initialize` method as it is the most consistent option in that the `quantity` **always** has a value.

Comment: I forgot to add the code, but I just updated it. I have the default value of quantity set in the migration file. Not sure if that changes what I need to do or not.

Comment: The default database value doesn't matter, in a sense, as the new object created by `build` or `new` won't get the default *database* value until you save the record and then re-fetch it.

Comment: I used the after_initialize method. It works perfectly. And, yeah, that makes sense. Thanks so much for your answer. I have no idea why I couldn't have just figured that out. It was so simple. I think I racked my brain so long trying to think of a complex reason for why it was happening, that I ended up overloading it. Haha. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is attempting do to arithmetic with a `nil` value, thus the message `nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal`.

As to why this happens, you'll need to do some digging to figure out where in the code the error arises. One clue is that the error implies the `nil` value is on the right side of the operation, e.g.:

```
bd = BigDecimal.new("0")
bd + nil # => nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal
```

as opposed to:

```
nil + bd # => undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass
```