# nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal - Ruby On Rails(rails 2.3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was try below codes.i got error for "nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal".
anyone help me.thanks.

**migration file**

```
class AddPaidAmountToVoucher < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :vouchers, :paid_amount, :decimal, :precision => 18, :scale => 2
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :vouchers, :paid_amount
  end
end
```

**Model class(voucher_payment.rb)**

```
after_update :update_voucher_paid_amount

def update_voucher_paid_amount
    voucher = self.voucher
    paidAmount = 0
    voucher.voucher_payments.each do |voucher_payment|
      paidAmount += voucher_payment.paid_amount if voucher_payment.is_approved == true
    end
    voucher.paid_amount = paidAmount 

    voucher.save
  end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985967/nil-cant-be-coerced-into-bigdecimal-ruby-on-rails

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779368/ruby-on-rails-nil-cant-be-coerced-into-bigdecimal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails nil can't be coerced into BigDecimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779368/ruby-on-rails-nil-cant-be-coerced-into-bigdecimal)

Comment: Thanks.now it's working

Answer (score 1):

While looping through `voucher.voucher_payments` one/some of the voucher_payment has paid_amount as nil.

```
voucher_payment.paid_amount = nil
```

So when you add paidAmount to a nil value, this error shows up.

Comment: @thanu Can you accept the answer if this solved the issue?